# Alternative Excel Filter Formula to remove zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried to filter a table for zeros. In the end, I need a list of items where the number is not zero.
So what I need is the following

[image: Picture 1]

I have tried with the following Excel Formula

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(DatenC!A2:DatenC!B84,DatenC!B2:DatenC!B84>0),"No Data available")
```

[image: Picture 2]

On my Laptop, it worked. But when I tried it on my pc it didn't work because the filter formula is a beta feature.

it changes the formula to this on my pc

```
=IFERROR(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(DatenC!A2:DatenC!B84,DatenC!B2:DatenC!B84>0),"No Data available")
```

Is anybody have an idea of how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You have two options: get a version of Excel on your PC that supports the new features,  or don't use `FILTER`

Comment: Add a header row to your data.  Select the header row and apply filter.  Select the header cell over the column with 0 results.  Make sure select all is selected, then uncheck 0.  The displayed information will just be no zeros.  Note the other rows are still there, their rows are just hidden by the filter command.